# javascript - use html ID tag or add property to element?

Tags: javascript

I am using Prototype.js, but this probably applies to jQuery as well: I have a html list with a bunch of rows where each row is related to an object in javascript which is contained in an array. So:

```
<ul>
    <li id="0">blah</li>
    <li id="1">blahblah></li>
</ul>
```

I am currently using the id tag to find the javascript object refers to. So when the user clickes on the row, the event code will look something like:

```
var clickedItem = event.findElement('li');
if (clickedItem) {
    var itemID = clickedItem.identify();
    var foundBlah = blahList[itemID];
```

Is using the ID tags a bad idea and should I instead be adding a property to each row when it is created, such as:

```
   var blah = new Blah('blah');
   $(list).insert(<li>blah</li>).blah = blah;
```

and then just retrieving that value in the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Prototype, but in jQuery, this sounds like a job for [`.data()`](http://api.jquery.com/data/), which allows you to attach arbitrary data to an element:

```
$(list).insert($("<li>blah</li>").data("blah", blah));

// later...
var blah = $(event.target).data("blah");
```

**Update**

Prototype has methods [`Element#store`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/store/) and [`Element#retrieve`](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/Element/prototype/retrieve/) which similarly allow you to attach metadata:

```
$(list).insert(new Element("li").insert("blah").store("blah", blah));

// later...
var blah = event.findElement("li").retrieve("blah")
```

Comment: There is something in prototype called store, as in: $(list).insert(...).store('key', 'value'); and later: .retrieve('key') on the element. Though I don't know why I would use this rather than just add a property to the element.

Comment: @BobTurbo — Yes, it looks like Prototype's `.store()`/`.retrieve()` are equivalent to `.data()`.  I'd consider that the ideal way to do what you describe, as it allows you to attach JS-specific data to an element without cluttering the DOM.